# binary classification for imbalanced data

Tags: python

In data mining, I use a machine learning algorithm to solve the binary classification.
However, the distribution of data samples is extremely imbalanced.
The ratio between good samples and bad samples is as high as 500:1.
Which methods can be used to solve the binary classification for imbalanced data?

Comment: Some ml algorithms have a `weights` parameter that can be used to give a higher weight to some samples (X500 in your case). You can also duplicate your scarce samples.

Answer (score 1):

One standard method in this case would be to use oversampling, so artificially inflate your smaller class. In sklearn most of the machine learning algorithms have a parameter like "class_weight" with which you can define how much each class should be given weight to (for example in a randomforest). The same holds for most machine learning algorithms in R.

Another way of approaching this would be to artificially create data for your underrepresented class (SMOTE for example).

Also you could try to use deeplearning to create this artificial data for your underrepresented class. The approach I tried was to use a Variational Autoencoder and then sample from the underlying distribution to generate fake data for the class you want: https://lschmiddey.github.io/fastpages_/2021/03/17/data-augmentation-tabular-data.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Synthetic Minority Oversampling Techniques(SMOTE) or Adasyn to tackle this. Try both methods and finalize based on your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use asymmetric loss functions which penalize models differently based on the label of data. In your case the loss function should penalize errors in "bad" samples much more than errors in "good" samples. In this way the model pays more attentions to the rare data points.